# can I clean tmp folder in rails project - ruby on rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4

I have a simple question: 
can I delete the content in the tmp folder in my rails project? Or will there be some errors?
I don't want to try because I am afraid...

Answer (score 0):

Yes , the tmp folder will be automatically regenerated if you delete it